# Magento CE 2.3.2 TypeError: setCouponCodeAction.registerDataModifier is not a function

Tags: checkout, coupon, magento2.3.2

After updating Magento CE 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 incl. updating libsodium we have trouble with our checkout.

When trying to access the checkout - does not matter which way - we get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: setCouponCodeAction.registerDataModifier is not a function.
```

In our theme we moved the voucher section to the right sidebar but that wasn't a problem in Magento CE v2.3.1.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Can you add detail on how you achieved your change

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I'm encountering the same thing.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just blocker for my actual task

So as temporary solution I commented this component:

```
<item name="captcha" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/captcha</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">captcha</item>
    <item name="formId" xsi:type="string">sales_rule_coupon_request</item>
    <item name="configSource" xsi:type="string">checkoutConfig</item>
</item>
```

in vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: This solution is working but does not know what is the impact of commenting the code

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you have the old (2.3.1) version of SalesRule/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-coupon-code.js in your local browser cache. Clear your cache or start a new private browsing session, and the error will disappear.

Comment: I am getting this error even in a private window and after clearing browser cache and cookies.

Comment: I have also faced the same problem tried the solution mention but did not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Also had this error.

Solved by simply using incognito/clearing local browser cache. (Magento 2.2.x => 2.3.x)