# Magento 2.3.5 checkout page not loading ( captcha error in console)

Tags: magento2.3, checkout-page

I have installed fresh setup of magento 2.3.5 and was testing the overall checkout flow. But when I add product to cart and go to checkout page, loader continues to load and basically nothing happens and form section is not visible.

I tried to check these ref. but no luck:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23518
[Magento CE 2.3.2 TypeError: setCouponCodeAction.registerDataModifier is not a function](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282433/magento-ce-2-3-2-typeerror-setcouponcodeaction-registerdatamodifier-is-not-a-fu)

Here is the console error I get:

```
captcha.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: setCouponCodeAction.registerDataModifier is not a function
at UiClass.initialize (captcha.js:44)
at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
at new UiClass (class.js:49)
at Object.initComponent (layout.js:137)
at fire (jquery.js:3238)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3368)
at Object.deferred.<computed> (jquery.js:3467)
at fire (jquery.js:3238)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3368)
at Object.deferred.<computed> [as resolve] (jquery.js:3467)
```

Any help much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Any third party extension or something install?

Comment: yes thanks was able to fix it by removing custom module

Comment: tr to fix the error into extension.